# In javascript How to push the Same object Twice into an array with some modification without overriding the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to push the same object into an array with some modification to the object. But when i do modification and push the object the first object which is in array is getting overrided.

```
var details = [{"name":"john","id":2,"personalEmail":"john@gmail.com","workEmail":"wa2@gmail.com"}];    var searchData = "joh";
var pattern1 = new RegExp("(?:^|[\\s\@])"+searchData, "i");
var data = [];
for(var i=0;i<details.length;i++){
  var name = details[i].name;
  if(pattern1.test(name)){
   var dom = name.replace(name.match(pattern1), '<strong>'+ name.match(pattern1) + '</strong>');
   details[i].name = dom;        
   data.push(details[i]);
   console.log("first ::::"+JSON.stringify(data));
   if(details[i].workEmail != null){
 details[i].personalEmail = details[i].workEmail;
     data.push(details[i]);
     console.log("second::::"+JSON.stringify(data));
   }
  }
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2311/.
We can see the output in Console (F12 Console tab).

Output Getting:

```
second::::[{"name":"<strong>joh</strong>n","id":2,"personalEmail":"wa2@gmail.com","workEmail":"wa2@gmail.com"},{"name":"<strong>joh</strong>n","id":2,"personalEmail":"wa2@gmail.com","workEmail":"wa2@gmail.com"}]
```

Expected Output:

```
second::::[{"name":"<strong>joh</strong>n","id":2,"personalEmail":"john@gmail.com","workEmail":"wa2@gmail.com"},{"name":"<strong>joh</strong>n","id":2,"personalEmail":"wa2@gmail.com","workEmail":"wa2@gmail.com"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript objects are passed by the reference , so the two objects are the same but two references. You need to make a clone of the object for your requirement.
if you are using JQuery ,

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, details[i]);
```

Comment: Tried to create new object. But of no use. I amnot that good at javascript. Please correct me If I did in wrong way. http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2314/

Comment: Already tried that way. but its giving the same output. Please check output in console. For console statement that starts with "second..", first object i want personal email as john@gmail.com

Comment: I think you have given previous fiddle link.not an updated one

Comment: Its Still Same output.

Comment: It's not the same output ,http://jsfiddle.net/LQg7W/2317/  
  
first `::::[{"name":"<strong>joh</strong>n","id":2,"personalEmail":"john@gmail.com","workEmail":"wa2@gmail.com"}]`
  
second `::::{"name":"<strong>joh</strong>n","id":2,"personalEmail":"wa2@gmail.com","workEmail":"wa2@gmail.com"} `

Comment: Ah yes. My mistake. But we are already using underscore js. So used Underscore clone method to copy it.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript uses references for objects. As such, in your array, you're adding a reference to your first object, and then you're adding a second reference to the same object. Basically, there's only one object, and two references (kind of like a single file on a filesystem with two shortcuts to it) and so any change you make will appear for all references of that object.

You need to copy your object and then edit the copy. Check out this question: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

....or just use a library like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to accomplish copying. (Edit: Underscore doesn't actually have native support for deep copying, but [lodash](http://lodash.com/) [does](http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) - and you should probably be using that anyway.)

Comment: Used Underscore Js to Accomplish copying.

Answer (score 0):

It's the essentials of javascript. Treat all objects as reference type. To do your task you need to create new object and push it into array.